# How to fade the content of image view which reaches at the top & bottom while scrolling(Vertical)?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, scroll, fade

I had requirement as when ever we scroll images **(have several image views of 300*150 size on scroll view)** the alpha of the image must be gradually decreased/increased based upon scrolling.. so can any one help on this..

*Thanks in Advance*

need same as below but for image views

**need the fade as on the third image**

[image: Sample Image]

Comment: Try this [link](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/fade-transition-fade-images-in-and-out.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a gradient image (white to transparent here) and add it to an UIImageView on top of the content.

Comment: Keep in mind that the color of non-transparent part of the gradient image must match the background color of your scrollview. This will add a more realistic effect.

Comment: @Jilouc i know the way u discussed but i'm looking for more efficient way....thought that some one would help me other than this way so i posted the question....anyways thanks for your valuable answer